# О речевой избыточности

Tags: общие-вопросы

Недавно проскользнула тема с 22 вопросами, где требовалось устранить речевую избыточность. Из интереса для себя озадачился. Легко справился с 21 вопросом. Но в ступор ввёл самый первый: "Он приехал на стройку два года назад". Разве тут можно что-то сделать? Конечно, можно написать что-то вроде "Он на стройке два года", но ведь это не будет отражать смысл исходного предложения. Есть ли в нём речевая избыточность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, там опечатка и имели в виду "тому назад", в котором "тому" можно убрать. А может, это ловушка, ведь на самом деле в предложении всё правильно.

Comment: Полагаю, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так: Вот уже два года, как он приехал на стройку. Я бы не стал относить такие выражения как " два года назад" к речевой избыточности. Здесь, на мой взгляд, речевая избыточность стерлась. Причыны могут быть разные. Однако вопрос интересный. Надо узнать, что думают об этом специалисты Грамота.ру и Грамма.ру.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду задание, которое было выставлено здесь?

Comment: Да, я имею ввиду именно это задание.